# How to remove or hide the navigation button in mobile build in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When the player build settings is set as **fullscreen** with **render outside safe area**.

Still the build doesnt make any difference.The navigation button is not hidden or removed?

[image]

What is the workaround for removing the navigation bar or making it as autohide when dragged up it is visible?
The build settings doesnt make any difference

[image]

I did followed
http://zehfernando.com/2015/unity-tidbits-changing-the-visibility-of-androids-navigation-and-status-bars-and-implementing-immersive-mode/

But the methods were showing as deprecated..and I am not so sure how to furthur implement using the new method.
[image]

Also if followed in this approach, it might required to be maintained everytime if something is updated or deprecated in the android api.